# why is css background image not showing

Tags: html, css

Why is the CSS background image not showing when I launch the file on my local desktop? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" text="type/css" href="discovery.css">
<title>Programming Club Official Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Programming Club Official Blog</h1>
<p>This is a blog that allows member of the programming club to keep in 
  touch about what we are doing in the club. Feel free to look at the code by pressing Ctrl-U! ~ Nathan Tran</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS code:

```
html {
background:url (http://smashingyolo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Best- 
Website-Background-Images10.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

I promise to accept the answer that helps me the most so please debug the code for me. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax errors:

1. Put the link in quotes
2. Remove the space between url and (

```css
html {
background:url("http://smashingyolo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Best-Website-Background-Images10.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" text="type/css" href="discovery.css">
<title>Programming Club Official Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Programming Club Official Blog</h1>
<p>This is a blog that allows member of the programming club to keep in 
  touch about what we are doing in the club. Feel free to look at the code by pressing Ctrl-U! ~ Nathan Tran</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IT WORKED! I didn't know that removing a space made it work. I used a different text editor before and it still worked when I put the space. I guess the space isn't proper code... :(

Comment: Don't worry, I accepted your answer. If you think my question helped you learn, vote it up!

Answer (score 0):

Is not required to add image URL under quote.

Problem is wrong URL. There is space in image URL. Remove space between 
**Best-** and **Website**

http://smashingyolo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Best-%20Website-Background-Images10.jpg

```css
html {
background:url(http://smashingyolo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Best-Website-Background-Images10.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" text="type/css" href="discovery.css">
<title>Programming Club Official Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Programming Club Official Blog</h1>
<p>This is a blog that allows member of the programming club to keep in 
  touch about what we are doing in the club. Feel free to look at the code by pressing Ctrl-U! ~ Nathan Tran</p>
</body>
</html>
```